# How do I fix Delphi Prism ASP.NET error: "Parser Error Message: 'Oxygene' is not a supported language"

Tags: .net, asp.net, delphi, delphi-prism, remobjects

I have written an ASP.NET web application (not site) in Delphi Prism. Everything works fine on my devlopment machine, but when I install it on a test server I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'Oxygene' is not a supported language.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.pas" Inherits="MyApp.Global_asax" Language="Oxygene" %>


Source File: /MyApp/global.asax    Line: 1
```

I've read everything I can find on the web. Several articles mention a RemObjects page (http://devcenter.remobjects.com/articles/?id={B549AFB8-04C8-4574-B185-30DE14369E66}) which unfortunately, no longer exists.

Some links suggest that you can just change Language="Oxygene" to Language="C#". Trying this produces a different error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ForgottenUsernameLinkButton_Click' and no extension method 'ForgottenUsernameLinkButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.login_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Anybody else experienced these problems?

Comment: This has been discussed in Delphi.Prism newsgroups, accessible via NNTP and also via web interface. Namely, the link to discussion is https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=51211

Comment: @Eugene - I've seen the thread, but it doesn't contain a solution to this problem. I'm using ASP.NET web application, not a web site.

Comment: there were more discussions on the topic during Autumn, that is the thing I remember for sure. I.e. you probably will have more success asking in newsgroup - the authors (Marc and other guys from RemObjects) answer in newsgroups quite actively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are several ways to solve this issue. The easiest way: If you control the server is by installing the command line edition.
2. Another way is precompiling, it: You'll need the [Web deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89F2C4F5-5D3A-49B6-BCAD-F776C6EDFA63) to do this. When you do this, make sure to uncheck the updatable option.
3. With the august 2010 build you can copy the .compiler, .codemodel, .pdb, .cirrus to Bin/, then to your web.config add something like:

`<system.codedom> 
      <compilers>

        <compiler language="Chrome" extension=".pas" type="RemObjects.Oxygene.CodeDom.OxygeneCodeProvider, RemObjects.Oxygene.CodeModel, Version=4.0.0.800, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3df3cad1b7aa5098" />

        <compiler language="Oxygene" extension=".pas" type="RemObjects.Oxygene.CodeDom.OxygeneCodeProvider, RemObjects.Oxygene.CodeModel, Version=4.0.0.800, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3df3cad1b7aa5098" /> 
    </compilers> 
  </system.codedom>`

Note that in this requires that the version number (4.0.0.800) has to match the dll version of the CodeModel dll you have.

Comment: Excellent answer Ck. I went with #2 and it seems to work fine so far.

Comment: Do you really need the .pdb? I thought this is just debug information?

Comment: You'd only need the .PDB dll id you wanna compile your ASP.NET site with debug info. which might be useful. That said, Oxygene 5 iirc eliminates that dll, so the point is moot for newer versions of the compiler.