# Difficulty running Web service in IIS - Oxygene

Tags: asp.net, delphi, iis

I created a web service by Delphi prism 2010 and it works properly in Delphi prism.

When I want to move that web service to IIS and use it it raise an error
`'Oxygene' is not a supported language.`

After searching this site I found a solution in topic [Fix Delphi Prism ASP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651867/how-do-i-fix-delphi-prism-asp-net-error-parser-error-message-oxygene-is-not)

I Installed RemObjects Elements but now when I want to use the web service it raises another error as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment it and can't check it. I have some ideas:

May be there are some version mismatch? it's common problem for Newtonsoft.Json in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

And you can fix it like this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

And look this: 
https://talk.remobjects.com/t/upgrade-to-oxygene-net-8-2-89-1893/7584

Comment: Thank you for your help it was because of Microsoft .net version